# How can I get the highest (and last) number from an API call in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm using the [backpack.tf](https://backpack.tf/developer) API for a Discord bot. I'm currently attempting to make a price command, using the API to find the prices of the items. Rather than returning the current price, the API returns all of the price updates, as shown below.

[image]

Only the last value in this call (85) is currently correct and updated. The code I'm using to send and log the results is as follows:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const superagent = require("superagent");
String.prototype.toProperCase = function() {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
};
module.exports = {
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        let item = args[0]
        let quality = args[1]
        let { body } = superagent
            .get(`https://backpack.tf/api/IGetPriceHistory/v1?appid=440&item=${item}&quality=${quality}&tradable=Tradable&craftable=Craftable&priceindex=0&key=5eeea0c9c995374dc219a4e2`);
        message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Price info of ${item.toProperCase()} (${quality.toProperCase()})`)
            .setDescription(`${response.history[HIGHESTNUMBER].value} refined metal`)
        )
    },
    aliases: ["price", "gp"]
}
```

Where `HIGHESTNUMBER` is shown in the code is where I need the highest number from the returned JSON. If and how am I able to complete this? Thanks.

Comment: So read the last item....

Comment: @espascarello This is simply a call for 1 of upwards of thousands of items, the value changes with each call.

Comment: So what is it? An array? An object?

Comment: There are 86 objects in this call, and I'm trying to get the last one, or the one named with the highest number (e.g 85)

Comment: So `var last = Object.keys(theObject).pop()`